# cloud foundry copy routes from one app to another

Tags: java, bash, shell, cloud-foundry

Cloud Foundry is it possible to copy missing routes from one app to another while doing blue green deployment?

I have an app with few manually added routes, while doing blue green deployment (automated through script) I want to copy missing/manually added routes into new app. Is it possible?

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

path="C:/Users/.../Desktop/cf_through_sh/appName.jar"

spaceName="development"
appBlue="appName"
appGreen="${appName}-dev"
manifestFile="C:/Users/.../Desktop/cf_through_sh/manifest-dev.yml"
domains=("domain1.com" "domain2.com")
appHosts=("host-v1" "host-v2")

evaluate_return_code (){
  ret=$1
  if [[ $ret != 0 ]]
  then
    exit $ret
  fi
}

switch_to_target_space() {
    space="development"
    echo "Change space to ${space}"
    cf t -s ${space}
    evaluate_return_code $?
}

push_new_release() {
    appGreen=$1
    if [ ! -f "${manifestFile}" ]; then
        echo "Missing manifest: ${manifestFile}";
        exit 1;
    fi

    if [ ! -f "${path}" ]; then
        echo "Missing artifact: ${path}";
        exit 1;
    fi
    echo "Deploying ${path} as ${appGreen}"
    cf push ${appGreen} -f ${manifestFile} -p ${path} --no-route
    evaluate_return_code $?
}

map_routes() {
    app=$1
    domains=$2
    shift
    appHosts=$3

    for  host in  ${appHosts[*]}; do
        echo "Mapping ${host} to ${app}"
        for  domain in  ${domains[*]}; do
            cf map-route ${app} ${domain} -n ${host}
            evaluate_return_code $?
        done
    done
}


unmap_routes() {
    app=$1
    domains=$2
    shift
    appHosts=$3

    for  host in  ${appHosts[*]}; do
        echo "Unmapping ${host} from ${app}"
        for  domain in  ${domains[*]}; do
            cf unmap-route ${app} ${domain} -n ${host}
        evaluate_return_code $?
        done
    done
}

rename_app() {
    oldName=$1
    newName=$2
    echo "Renaming ${oldName} to ${newName}"
    cf rename ${oldName} ${newName}
    evaluate_return_code $?
}

switch_names() {
    appBlue=$1
    appGreen=$2
    appTemp="${appBlue}-old"
    rename_app ${appBlue} ${appTemp}
    rename_app ${appGreen} ${appBlue}
    rename_app ${appTemp} ${appGreen}
}

stop_old_release() {
    echo "Stopping old ${appGreen} app"
    cf stop ${appGreen}
    evaluate_return_code $?
}

switch_to_target_space ${spaceName}
push_new_release ${appGreen}
map_routes ${appGreen} ${domains[*]} ${appHosts[*]}
unmap_routes ${appBlue} ${domains[*]} ${appHosts[*]}
switch_names ${appBlue} ${appGreen}
stop_old_release

echo "DONE"
exit 0;
```

Eg:
appblue has 5 roues

```
 1. host-v1.domain1.com
 2. host-v2.domain1.com
 3. host-v1.domain2.com
 4. host-v2.domain2.com
 5. manual-add.domain1.com //manually added route through admin UI
```

After blue green deployment through script app contains only 4 routes

```
 1. host-v1.domain1.com
 2. host-v2.domain1.com
 3. host-v1.domain2.com
 4. host-v2.domain2.com
```

How to copy missing 5th route? I don't want to pass host ***manual-add***  from script since it's added manually.

In general, is it possible to copy routes from one app to another if not mapped?

Comment: Have you looked at the `cf map-route` command? Docs available [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#map-route-manually).

Comment: @RowanJacobs yes I looked into it. Using that I can map routes if I know host and domain. Here just I want to copy routes from one app to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be done only through Jenkins (or any CI-CD tool). What we did in our case is, we had a `CF-Manifest-Template.yml` and `CF-Manifest-settings.json` and we had a gradle task that would apply the settings from JSON and fill the Manifest-temple and generate a `cf-manifest-generated.yml`

The gradle file will have a task that would do blue-green-deployment by using this generated manifest file and all the routes will be hard-coded in the manifest-file. This is the standard way of doing it.

But if you want to copy route from an App running in Cloud Foundry and copy thos routes to another-app, then you would need to write a `REST Client` that connects to Cloud Foundry `CloudController` and gets all the route of `App-A` and then creates routes to `APP-B`

It is pretty simple !!

Write a REST Client that executes this command

> cf app APP-A

This will bring back the details of APP-A as a JSON Response. The response would have these parameters

```
Showing health and status for app APP-A in org Org-A / space DEV as arun2381985@yahoo.com...

name:              APP-A
requested state:   started
instances:         1/1
usage:             1G x 1 instances
routes:            ********
last uploaded:     Sat 25 Aug 00:25:45 IST 2018
stack:             cflinuxfs2
buildpack:         java_buildpack
```

Read this JSON response and collect the Routes of APP-A and then have that mapped for APP-B .. Its pretty simple

Comment: great!! Thanks for the hint. I was able to do it.

Comment: Thanks for Marking it the right answer. Please offer the bounty that was marked for this question :)

Comment: Hi, though it serves my purpose, not sure if this is the best approach. Will wait for couple of days, if not getting anymore answers then for sure I'll award the bounty.